# How to get over "Theano has no sparse vector" error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, sparse-matrix

The following code works fine when the tensor is a `dmatrix` as follows:

```
A = T.dmatrix('A') # Input tensor

X, updates = theano.scan(lambda i: T.sum((A+A[i])*(T.neq(A*A[i],0)), axis=1),
                         sequences=T.arange(A.shape[0]))

compute = function([A], X)
```

Sample input:

```
a = [[1,2,3,0,9],[3,2,6,2,7],[0,0,0,8,0],[1,0,0,0,3]]
compute(a)
```

Corresponding output:

```
array([[ 30.,  33.,   0.,  14.],
       [ 33.,  40.,  10.,  14.],
       [  0.,  10.,  16.,   0.],
       [ 14.,  14.,   0.,   8.]])
```

The real pain comes into play when I try converting this to a sparse matrix.

```
A = sparse.csr_matrix(name='A', dtype='int64')
```

The following error pops up when `X` is compiled:

```
...
... 
NotImplementedError: Theano has no sparse vectorUse X[a:b, c:d], X[a:b, c:c+1] or X[a:b] instead.
```

I also tried substituting the addition and multiply operations in the scan function with `sparse.basic.add` and `sparse.basic.mul` respectively. No matter what I do, the above error persists.

Please help. What should I do to fix this?